# IdentityServer enable reference tokens

Tags: c#, identityserver3

Current we are using JWT tokens to authenticate (which works) but I would like to use reference tokens.
Currently our config is like this:

```
public static class Config
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures identity server
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServer(this IAppBuilder app, CormarConfig config)
    {

        // Create our options
        var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "Cormar API",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
            IssuerUri = "https://cormarapi-test.azurewebsites.net",

            // Not needed
            LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
            {
                EnableHttpLogging = true,
                EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
                EnableKatanaLogging = true,
                WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true
            },

            // In membory crap just to get going
            Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory().Configure(config),         

            // Disable when live
            EnableWelcomePage = true
        };

        // Setup our auth path
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions);
        });
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the identity server to use token authentication
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServerTokenAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://cormarapi-test.azurewebsites.net/identity",
            DelayLoadMetadata = true,
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local,
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api" },

            ClientId = "api",
            ClientSecret = "not_my_secret"
        });

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the certificate
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        var certPath = $"{ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory }App_Data\\idsrv3test.pfx";
        var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "3A1AFB6E1DC5C3F341E63651542C740DA4148866", false);
        certStore.Close();

        // If we are on azure, get the actual self signed certificate, otherwise return the test one
        return certCollection.Count > 0 ? certCollection[0] : new X509Certificate2(certPath, "idsrv3test");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure the identity service factory with custom services
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IdentityServerServiceFactory Configure(this IdentityServerServiceFactory factory, CormarConfig config)
    {
        var serviceOptions = new EntityFrameworkServiceOptions { ConnectionString = config.SqlConnectionString };
        factory.RegisterOperationalServices(serviceOptions);
        factory.RegisterConfigurationServices(serviceOptions);

        factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(new DefaultCorsPolicyService { AllowAll = true }); // Allow all domains to access authentication
        factory.Register(new Registration<DbContext>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<DbContext>()));
        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IUserService>());
        factory.ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IClientStore>());
        factory.ScopeStore = new Registration<IScopeStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IScopeStore>());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have added the **ClientId** and **ClientSecret** to **IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions**.
If I set my client's **AccessTokenType** to reference and try to get a reference token, it works and I get a response like this:

```
"access_token": "631783604e9c35e6b401605fe4809075",
"expires_in": 3600,
"token_type": "Bearer"
```

But if I then try to access an resource on my server, I get a 401 unauthorized error.
If I swap back to a JWT **AccessTokenType** I can authenticate and then access my resource with no issues.

As a note, I had set the **ClientSecret** and the **ScopeSecret** to the same value, so I would expect it to work.

Am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: Probably not related to the problem but i believe your are missing a backslash here `var certPath = $"{ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory }App_Data\\idsrv3test.pfx";` between `BaseDirectory` and `App_Data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot locally verify a token when using the reference token type. Since it's unstructured data, with no digitally verifiable signature, your API needs to check the token with IdentityServer.

To do this, change your `ValidationMode` to `ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint` or `ValidationMode.Both`

From the docs:

> ValidationMode can be either set to Local (JWTs only), ValidationEndpoint (JWTs and reference tokens using the validation endpoint - and Both for JWTs locally and reference tokens using the validation endpoint (defaults to Both). - https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/consuming/options.html

Comment: Interesting, I shall change this and see if it fixes the issue.